# In React why does my boolean repeats itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
    const [isImportant, setIsImportant] = React.useState("Yes")

    let isImportantBoolean = false;
    function handleClick() {
        isImportantBoolean = !isImportantBoolean;
        isImportantBoolean ? setIsImportant('Yes') : setIsImportant('No');
        console.log(isImportantBoolean);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="state">
            <h1 className="state--title">Is state important to know?</h1>
            <div onClick={handleClick} className="state--value">
                <h1>{isImportant}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When I click the button the console.log pattern goes like `true false true true false` it repeats the `true`. But when I remove the `isImportantBoolean ? setIsImportant('Yes') : setIsImportant('No')` console.log goes normal and does not repeat `true`. Why is this behaviour is occuring?

Comment: Because it gets reset and re-defined on every render that happens after you set your isImportant state

Comment: You should probably store the actual boolean in state, and choose the string to render in the JSX. `<h1>{isImportant ? "Yes" : "No"}</h1>`

Comment: Any time you update state, `isImportantBoolean` becomes `false` because it's explicitly being set to `false`.  If a value needs to persist across renders, put it in state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isImportantBoolean` gets reset and re-defined on every render that happens after you set your `isImportant` state. You should do things vise-versa and store your boolean value there instead, and conditionaly display either "Yes" or "No" based on boolean value

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
  const [isImportant, setIsImportant] = React.useState(true)

  function handleClick() {
      setImportant(!isImportant);
      console.log(isImportant);
  }

  return (
      <div className="state">
          <h1 className="state--title">Is state important to know?</h1>
          <div onClick={handleClick} className="state--value">
              <h1>{isImportant ? "Yes" : "No"}</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Oh I see it happens because renders screen everytime.

Comment: Exactly! In react, re-render fires after each `setState` call and all the variables and functions defined inside component will get re-declared on each re-render (unless you memorize them with useCallback, useMemo or useRef hooks) , so having your isImportantBoolean not being a state variable, it was getting re-set to its default value every render.